# How to effectively read excel in pandas dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have unfortunately no experience with excel dataset in pandas and its first time that I have to work with it.
The dataset look like this:

```
 Columa_1   Column_2   Column3      Column4   Column5
  Germany   Business    Automobile   32400     text1
                        Pesticide    348700    text2
                        Chemisty     97245     text3
            Homework    Cleaning     56248     text3
                        Cooking      67354     text4
            Schooling   attending    78464     text5
```

The dataset in excel look like this, from excel point of view its clear that `Column_1` applies to all rows, similarly values: `Pesticide` and `chemisty` also has `Column_2` as `Business` etc. etc.

However, when I change this sheet into Pandas dataframe, the whole blank are replaced with NA's :( How to deal with this so intuitive idea of Excel from Pandas point of view? Is there any way-around?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) (forward fill) to carry non-NA values forward:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(...).ffill()
```